# Performance - frequently rendering the same large set of images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, optimization, web-performance

There's a game with a considerable amount of items. I've got a website that's an item browser for this game.

There's a search field. If the search field is empty, all items are drawn, which means a couple hundred `div`s with backgrounds (I'm using CSS sprites for the images). Screenshot for better reference:
[image]
Currently, every item image is a `div` wrapped in an `ItemIcon` component, and it is mounted and unmounted as the array of item names to be drawn changes.

**The issue**:

- Whenever the search field is cleared (so all items are drawn), the website hangs for a noticeable fraction of a second.

Performance measured by Chrome's Devtools:
[image] 
The heavy part is taken mostly by hundreds of `<ItemIcon/>` mounts.

What could I do about it? I think that setting the icons to `display:none` would be far more performant than mounting/unmounting them. Is there anything facilitating this approach?

Comment: Have you used keys properly? Also do you need to show them all *at once* ?

Comment: Showing them all at once is very much desired. Every item has an unique key. `{currentItems.map(itemName => (<ItemIcon key={itemName} scale={2} itemName={itemName}></ItemIcon>))}` and every element of `currentItems` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the items in chunks in different microtasks, thus reducing the lag:

```
  const CHUNK = 10;
  for(let i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i += CHUNK) {
     setItems(items => items.concat( toAdd.slice(i, i + CHUNK) ) );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think that setting the icons to display:none would be far more performant than mounting/unmounting them.

This is a right direction to go in. 
It will shave off some performance points by avoiding rendering items when the search term updates.

You can look at using toggling a CSS classname with this property rule on items matching a search query.

There is the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package for computing conditional class names.

Say, the initial object structure for your gallery items is:

```
[
  {
    id, // unique identifier for item
    iconURI, // image item URL
   }
]
```

You could add an additional property in the object to determine whether to show the item or not.

```
[
  {
    id, // unique identifier for item
    iconURI, // image item URL
    hidden // whether item is shown in gallery
   }
]
```

`hidden` property of an item will be updated on the following conditions:

1. On initial rendering of the items in the gallery, `hidden` property is set to `false`.
2. Upon a search query, `hidden` property is set to `false` if item matches search terms and `true` when it doesn't
3. When search is cleared, `hidden` property of items is set to `false`

For updates to `hidden` property of item in *cond.* **2** & **3**, you can decide to control whether an item re-renders on update by implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` and only allowing an render when `hidden` property changes.

You could include property rules for `hidden` class selector in your stylesheet.

```css
.hidden {
  display:none
}
```

Relevant lifecycle methods for an item like this will be similar to:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextProps.hidden !== this.props.hidden
}

render() {
   const { iconURI, hidden } = this.props

   return (
     <div
       className={classnames('some-default-item-classname', {hidden: hidden})}>
       <img src={iconURI} />
     </div>
   )
}
```